# Is there any issue in imputing missing observations when the missing observations are related to each other?

Tags: data-imputation

Say that we have a cross-sectional dataset with two variables, A and B.

Also suppose that A and B are related to each other in some way. Now, there are some rows for which only A is missing, and some for which only B is missing. There are no rows for which both A and B are missing.

Now say that I want to impute these missing values by just taking the average of A and the average of B.

Would this be problematic, given that A and B are related to each other?

Comment: imputing the missing values by taking the average of those variables is problematic for a billion reasons, but you have indeed landed on one of them